# Creating retractable forms using js and css

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have a page, which is supposed to be a lot of buttons, the buttons are located 3 pieces in a row, you need to implement functionality that when you click on the button will open a form below it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa90i.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6OvN.png)

I don't know js very well, so I tried to find a solution on the internet, one such solution was to add and take away a visibility class (using jquery), but I think this solution is very bad

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".open_button").on("click", function () {
    $('.open_button[data-modal-id="' + $(this).data("modal-id") + '"]').addClass("add_margin_bottom");
  });

  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (
      !$(e.target).closest(".modal").length &&
      !$(e.target).closest(".open_button").length
    ) {
      console.log(555);
      $(".open_button").removeClass("add_margin_bottom");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like I usually use:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-button');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const formContainer = button.nextElementSibling;

    formContainer.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.form-container {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form-container.active {
  display: table-caption;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-container">
  <button class="toggle-button">Button One</button>
  <div class="form-container">
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Marks">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="buttons-container">
  <button class="toggle-button">Button Two</button>
  <div class="form-container">
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Marks">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanantion  :**

In the Javascript part , I am accessing button through className . After that I will made changes so that I will shart showing the active css part . Initially it is display none which don't show anything but when you click Js part change css part to active of that particular child and it will show us the form.

If you have any query let me know . I will surely help.